# Unable select area of the screenshot for cropping (Greenshot software)

Tags: crop, greenshot

I am using Windows 10 with Greenshot 1.2.10.6.  The area I want to keep is reduced to 1/4 inch square.  The square moves to a different location when I try to expand it.

What I have tried:
1. I have uninstall, reboot and reinstall the mouse driver, it doesn't help.
   The only change to my pc that I could think of is Windows updates, it was working before.
2. Greenshot 1.2.10.6 is the latest, no fixes available.
[quarter inch area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHsaA.jpg)

Thanks,
Lynn

Comment: Microsoft's preinstalled Snipping Tool and "Snip & Sketch" don't do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use different software? I prefer FastStone Capture for screen prints. Not only is it easier to edit screen captures, but it has built-in zoom options for those captures.